# jQuery .scroll .animate for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs that I'm trying to keep on the page. I don't want them to move. Both have a unique id: search_box and menuButton. I tried implementing the following code and it worked for the part with the search_box id:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
      $("#search_box")
        .stop()
        .animate({
          "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 5) + "px"
        }, 0);
```

However when I tried to do it for the second div, it didn't work. I tried to create a class called test and to add the class to both divs and it didn't work. I tried $("#search_box" "#menuButton"). Since I'm very knew to js, at this point I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with css

```
#search_box, #menuButton {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Another thing, this is way to use multiple jquery selector

```
$("#search_box, #menuButton")
```

Comment: Worked with the css but needed to add width 100% otherwise there was some overlapping. However it didn't work with: $("#search_box, #menuButton"). Either way thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#search_box", "#menuButton")
```

use comma as a separator.

Comment: That didn't work. It made the first div stay in its position and the second one scrolled normally. I'm honestly so lost at this point